# Spring security oauth2 login with google

Tags: spring, security, oauth-2.0

I want to create a login with google option and give authorities to the user depending on the user info returned. I've successfully done what I want for login with github following this tutorial:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-principal-authorities-extractor

which basically uses @EnableOAuth2Sso annotation and the following properties

> security.oauth2.client.client-id
>
> security.oauth2.client.client-secret
>
> security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri
>
> security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri
>
> security.oauth2.client.scope
>
> security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri

I can't do the same for google, so the problem should be in application.properties. I register my app with google, download the json that is given to me along with id & secret, but there seems to be missing the uri for **security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri** property. I've searched online for that uri and tried to run the app with some values but with no success. Am I right that I need this property and how do I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to request this information during authorization via scopes. This information is returned in the Identity Token and not the Access Token. If you requested the identity information you can also call the Google OAuth endpoint with the Access Token which returns the Identity Token.

Comment: **security.oauth2.client.scope= googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile** These are the scopes I use. You probably mean: **security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri -> Access Token security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri -> Identity Token** Do I undestand correctly? _If you requested the identity information you can also call the Google OAuth endpoint with the Access Token which returns the Identity Token_ I don't know what you mean with the above. What I'm asking is where I can find the Identity token URI

Comment: **security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
security.oauth2.client.scope= https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri= https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?alt=json**
These are the properties I use

Comment: The first step is the read the documentation. You will find that OAuth services have a discovery document. The document describes the service. https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration  This document is JSON that your software can read to configure itself. For example, the endpoint to call to get `userinfo` is: https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo

Comment: Is there any option to combine google calendar with spring 5 security? I already have the option of saving the token. Can I use an already obtained token in the google calendar api?

Comment: @Deluxxx - Create a new question.